# Can't import urllib3 from the current directory using relative imports

Tags: python, import, compilation, python-import, urllib

When I am trying to run a compiled Python executable, I am running into a weird problem with the requests module.

The exact Error message is as follows:

```
  File "tradingbot.py", line 11, in init tradingbot
  File "C:\Users\igors\Downloads\olympian_(4)\bin3\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "C:\Users\igors\Downloads\olympian_(4)\bin3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import urllib3
ImportError: No module named urllib3
```

As you can see, `__init__.py` file cannot import urllib3 module.

After following the path, we see the following directory:

[image]

After that, I decided to look into `__init__.py`, and found the following import code:

```
try:
    from . import urllib3
except ImportError:
    import urllib3
    sys.modules['%s.urllib3' % __name__] = urllib3
```

As you can see, the line that Error message refers to is `import urllib3`.

The problem is, why the program struggles with finding a folder containing the urllib3 module which is clearly located in the same directory as **init** file?

Please keep in mind that the program should work without having Python or any other libraries pre-installed on the user's PC. It should collect all the files from its own resources.

P.S. People asked me to show the urllib3 folder contents, so here it is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably int the urllib3 folder there is a .py file you need to import. Or you can just import everything at once. You can do those things respectively like this:

```
import urllib3.[file you want to import]
from urllib3 import *
```

Comment: Tried changing `import urllib3` to `import urllib3.file`, but returned same error: `ImportError: No module named urllib3.file`

Comment: Yea but you have to change the "file" in urllib3.file to the .py file that is inside your urllib3 folder that you need. By the way, try this one also: `from urllib3 import *`

Answer (score 0):

usually python module should contain `__init__.py` itself

could you provide more information on what your `urllib3` folder contains?

as well, you could try to take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html or https://www.docker.com/ if you don't want to install anything in pc

Comment: Just added the urllib3 folder screenshot

Comment: I've tried to remake your folder structure on ubuntu running script with pre-installed python in a regular way python script runs (not executable .pyc) and everything works just fine.
There is a chance that problem is in the way you try to build it from source on windows. I would highly recommend you to try running all of this in a docker container, if you have a possibility.